# Autocomplete field without selecting full suggestion with containing only entered part

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a autocomplete field working right. But when I entered partial text without selecting it erases the entered part when I pressed the search botton. I don't want this. I want to show suggestions but when user enters partial I want to save that value in search code. How can I do this ? Best Regards..

Answer (score 0):

```
                change: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#<%=hdn.ClientID %>").val("");
                    $("#<%=hdnOneriKayitNo.ClientID %>").val("");                        
                    $("#<%=txt.ClientID %>").val("");
                   
                },
```

I erased $("#<%=txt.ClientID %>").val("");in autocomplete code and it worked.